# Is is possible to read csv or parquet file using same code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Does any one know if it is possible to read either a csv or parquet file into a spark using the same code.

My use case here is that in production, I will be using large parquet files, but for unit tests, I would like to use CSVs. I'm using something like the following code:

```
spark.read().schema(schema).load(path);
```

This fails in the CSV case with the following exception:

```
file.csv is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [78, 9, 78, 10]
```

I suspect that spark defaults to parquet, and this won't work, but I wanted to check first.

Comment: what is your path form? Whatever, I think you should set the format.

Comment: I have a similar use case. I thought by now spark would have a mechanism to detect the type of file(CSV, parquet) and read the file with a single API :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spark.read.schema(schema).load(path);` Without mentioning **`format()`** then spark defaults to reading `parquet` file.

If you are reading **csv** file then we need to mention **`.format("csv")`** to let spark know we are trying to read a csv file or else spark will read the file as **parquet**.

`spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load(path)`

Comment: What if we don't know which one?  While there's always the fallback to `try <fail> except:` i'm wondering if there were an actual test `getFileFormat()` or similar

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, not sure if there is any method available, one way I could think of is read the file name and get the file extension to check if its `csv,json,parquet`

Comment: Yes but it's not fun to do the code for reading the files: I do have that code but it's four lines that takes a bit of effort.